# How to setup an Arduino virtual breadboard. Is Arduino Toolkit needed?

Tags: arduino, bread-board

I installed [Virtual Breadboard](http://www.virtualbreadboard.com/Main.aspx?TAB=8) 4.29.0. When I run the basic blink tutorial example it says that there is an error because I need the Arduino toolkit.

So I downloaded the Arduino 1.0.4 tools, but it's not really clear on if this is what I need or if it is how to integrate it.

What is the way forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you activated the Arduino Toolkit? You need to activate it before you can use the features. You should have all the ferences in the Toolkit order.
The Toolkit you need can be purchased here http://www.virtualbreadboard.com/Main.aspx?TAB=5
The invoice number is the serial activation code.

Comment: noooooooooo.... I was hoping I could use this without having to buy the Arduino. I wanted to see if I liked it before I bought. Oh well. Thanks for the info.

Comment: You do not need to buy the Arduino board. You need to buy the "Arduino Toolkit" software from the link I gave you in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Arduino Toolkit is a Virtual Breadboard pay-feature and is needed to support Arduino emulation.

You can purchase at the webshop (updated url  )
http://www.virtualbreadboard.com/Main.aspx?TAB=WebShop

Virtual Breadboard is also running a KickStarter right now ( Jan 2015 ) where you can pick up an Arduino Toolkit license with a big discount ( Virtual TINKERER Reward )

https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/683231209/virtual-breadboard-pcb-direct/